# spring statemachine for multiple thread concurrently

Tags: java, spring, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I am having 20 concurrent user processing orders in separate thread. How do I maintain the state using spring state machine?

I am trying:

```
public class myclass extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<OrderState, OrderEvents>

 @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<OrderState, OrderEvents> transitions)
            throws Exception {
        transitions
                .withExternal()
                .source(OrderState.A).target(OrderState.B)
                .event(OrderEvents.X)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(OrderState.A).target(OrderState.C)
                .event(OrderEvents.Y)
@Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<OrderState, OrderEvents> config) throws Exception {
        config
                .withConfiguration()
                .autoStartup(true)
                .listener(new OrderStateMachineListener());
    }
```

But it on;y tells me state machine, not for which order:

```
@Override
    public void stateChanged(State<OrderState, OrderEvents> from, State<OrderState, OrderEvents> to) {
        System.out.println("Order state changed to " + to.getId());
    }
```

I have other option of this but this option doesn't look good for each event:

```
stateMachine.stop();
        stateMachine
                .getStateMachineAccessor()
                .doWithAllRegions(access -> access.resetStateMachine(new DefaultStateMachineContext<>(sourceState, null, null, null)));
        stateMachine.start();
        stateMachine.sendEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked finally. I had to use @EnableStateMachineFactory on the configuration level instead of @EnableStateMachine, and from calling program:

```
@Autowired
StateMachineFactory<String, String> factory;

    public void getOrderStatus(long id) {
        StateMachine<String, String> stateMachine = factory.getStateMachine();
        stateMachine.start();
        stateMachine.sendEvent();
    }
```

Comment: Your state machine will be representing state of which ORDER?